# why does steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count() return time since reboot on Windows?

Tags: c++, std, c++-chrono

The following code on Windows 10:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    const auto p1 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    const auto p2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    std::cout << "system_clock seconds since epoch: "
        << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(
            p1.time_since_epoch()).count()
        << '\n';

    std::cout << "steady_clock seconds since epoch: "
        << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(
            p2.time_since_epoch()).count()
        << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
system_clock seconds since epoch: 1690157550
steady_clock seconds since epoch: 434342
```

So `steady_clock` appears to count the time since the last boot---even if I ask for time since the Epoch. To me this is not correct. It is not giving me the time since the Epoch.

Comment: From  [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock): "*This clock is not related to wall clock time (for example, it can be time since last reboot), and is most suitable for measuring intervals.*"

Comment: What do you think is the meaning of the word "epoch"?

Comment: @ALX23z January 1 1970 is the Epoch in Unix time. I expect the meaning to be the same in Windows. Maybe that is incorrect, but I believe that is what you get when you use steady_clock on Unix machines.

Comment: @dmedine An epoch is just any defined period of time. It isn't the name of any one specific point in time.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing) According to wikipedia 'Epoch' is a date, not a period of time. If 'epoch' referred to a period, the method `time_since_epoch` should be renamed.

Comment: `steady_clock`'s POSIX analog works same on Linux-like systems and on FreeBSD-based embedded OSes I encountered cases when it counts time since process's start.  the purpose of it to have timer which never goes back (even if system time might be rolled back for some reason, e.g. due to correction by NTP service)

Comment: @dmedine My comment was not meant to emphasize that epoch isn't a point in time (it's used interchangeably to indicate a period and the start of that period). It was to meant to indicate that it is a common noun, not just a proper noun as the Linux community would suggest (**an** epoch vs **the** Epoch). A clock's epoch means the period of time defined by the set of time points that clock can represent, or the start of that period, and doesn't imply any relation with the Unix Epoch (though they can be the same for certain clocks on certain implementations).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C++ standard does not impose any specific definition of an epoch, for all clocks, as a general requirement:

> 27.3 Cpp17Clock requirements [time.clock.req]
>
> 1A clock is a bundle consisting of a duration, a time_point, and a
> function now() to get the currenttime_point. The origin of the clock’s
> time_point is referred to as the clock’s epoch.

Full stop. A particular clock has some kind of an origin epoch, but what it is, is not specified in general. It is specified (if any) for each ***specific*** clock.

The `system_clock`'s origin, for example, is explicitly given as Jan 1 1970:

> Class system_clock [time.clock.system]
>
> [ ... ]
> Objects of type system_clock represent wall clock time from the system-wide realtime clock. Objects of type sys_time measure time since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC excluding leap seconds.

No such requirement is given for a `steady_clock`. The C++ standard leaves the origin, or the epoch, of `steady_clock` unspecified. The only guarantee that `steady_clock` gives you is that in never decreases. From the C++ standard:

> Class steady_clock       [time.clock.steady]
>
> [...]
>
> Objects of class steady_clock represent clocks for which values of
> time_point never decrease as physical time advances and for which values
> of time_point advance at a steady rate relative to real time. That is,
> the clock may not be adjusted.

That's it. There is no representation of `steady_clock` have any kind of a relationship to wall clock time and any specific wall clock-based starting point. As such MS-Windows' implementation of counting time since system boot is within the scope of this definition.

Now it is true that the clock would effectively reset itself on the next boot, and a question can be asked whether this strictly complies with the "never decrease" requirement, but that would be a different question. In so far is to why `steady_clock` does not count seconds since the Unix epoch, like `system_clock`, is because this is not required by the C++ standard.

Comment: Great answer. One comment, though is that one could also argue that Unix's implementation also violates the standard. If Unix adds an offset to (sort of) align the output of steady_clock so that it counts since the January 1 UTC moment, then that clock is adjusted.

Comment: But only if that's the case: that `steady_clock` on Unix is merely `system_clock` plus a fixed offset. That is very, very unlikely. I see no evidence of that. If anything, Unix time might also have 1/1/1970 UTC as an epoch, but also ticks during seconds, then this still meets `steady_clock` requirements. Note that C++20 explicitly defines a `utc_clock`, separately.

Comment: Yes but it must relate the first computation of a tick with some positive offset bringing it back to 1/1/1970. I am suggesting that _technically_ this too is an 'adjustment'. That may seem only a detail, but I suggest that this inconsistency (either in the spec or in implementations' obedience to it) is the reason for the misalignment---which for my specific problem is a problem.

Comment: @dmedine What problem is caused for you by `steady_clock` having different epochs on different platforms?

Comment: @HowardHinnant this is a very niche case. There is an open source data streaming library called lsl (https://github.com/sccn/labstreaminglayer). It uses `steady_clock` to timestamp data. Increasingly, users are expecting to be able to synchronize data streams across different recordings and file formats using the timestamps as reference---this isn't how the library was designed, but people are getting hung up on this specific inconsistency. We are contemplating solutions apart from saying 'don't do that' to people.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the details.  A `steady_clock` is like a stop watch.  It is great for timing things.  But it has no idea what time of day it is.  `steady_clock` time stamps from different processes (even the same program run different times) will have no guaranteed relationship to one another.  I'm afraid "don't do that" is as good as it gets, coupled with "use `system_clock` instead".  Starting with C++20, `system_clock`'s epoch is specified to the [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) epoch.  And prior to C++20, that was the existing practice.

Comment: @HowardHinnant thank you so much for the clarification. LSL uses timestamp information to synchronize streams on different time bases. It is battle tested and verified to be quite accurate. It uses `steady_clock` for this purpose. The problem with using `system_clock` in this case is the possibility that NTP will result in non-monotonic clock times---which is undesirable. The problem with `steady_clock` is this fundamental philosophical difference between Windows and Unix-based systems. I still think the spec is not truly being followed in both cases and hence the mismatch in the output.

Comment: @dmedline Could you combine both clocks? Calculate an offset at the start of your process with `system_clock` to fix the origin and use it on `steady_clock` for keeping monotony?

Comment: @Sebastian theoretically, yes, but the implications are pretty huge. LSL uses a clock synchronization algorithm to align data streams via timestamp information and clock offsets between streaming machines. Adding offsets to some but not all data streams' timestamps is non trivial. It could work provided everyone is using the same version of the library but back compatibility would become impossible and due to the nature of the library's distribution (some applications were made years ago, and are still in heavy use) the support nightmare is just unthinkable.

Comment: @dmedine So if you could choose any clock properties for all architectures, what would they be? If for backwards compatibility, you would not change the currently used clock on Windows nor Linux/Unix at all, it is difficult to improve. Or could it be an optional feature in newer versions of the library to use a more standard clock? Or would you rather like a way to change the clock for applications compiled with old library versions by patching or setting operating system or C++ configurations???

Comment: One way could be to use an offset to go to Unix Epoch only if the offset is large enough, so that it can be detected with certainty by other clients.